# Matlab uint8 division

Tags: matlab, integer-division

I found in Matlab, uint8(n) / uint8(255) == 0 when n <127, while uint8(n) / uint8(255) == 1 when n >=127. I don't know how this happened. Since in C/C++, it should be 0 as long as numerator is less than denominator.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html):

> MATLAB® rounds the results when dividing integer data types.

showing that MATLAB is not C or C++.

But you can use [the `idivide` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/idivide.html) and have control over rounding.